# Set a variable based on input argument in makefile

Tags: makefile

How can i set a debug variable when building target in makefile.

I want to set a `debug_flag` variable `true` only when I am building the target using `make target`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? What sort of flag are we talking about here? When do you want it set? What do you want it to apply to? Can you show us relevant portions of your makefile or a minimal sample makefile as an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below `Makefile`:

```
debug_flag=false

#here VAR is assigned with the value true only when you build target.
target: debug_flag=true
target:
    echo $(debug_flag)
```